# FIPS_rsa_x931_derive_ex function in openssl header file

Tags: c, openssl

Which header file in openssl contains the following function FIPS_rsa_x931_derive_ex ? I am getting implicit declaration of function warning when I use this function. I google for header file to be included but I have not found any information.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the function declaration to my program, warning disappeared.

int FIPS_rsa_x931_derive_ex(RSA *rsa, BIGNUM *p1, BIGNUM *p2, BIGNUM *q1,
    BIGNUM *q2, const BIGNUM *Xp1, const BIGNUM *Xp2, const BIGNUM *Xp, const
    BIGNUM *Xq1, const BIGNUM *Xq2, const BIGNUM *Xq, const BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB
    *cb);